# Authorization on .NET Core 2.1 Web API built on .NET Framework problem

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, authorization

I am trying to get the [Authroize] tag working on .NET Core 2.1 Web API project built on .NET Framework. There is no IAppBuilder.UseAuthorization(). I wrote my own JWT custom auth handler and tried the following in the Startup:

```
 services.AddAuthentication("Basic")
        .AddScheme&lt;BasicAuthenticationOptions, EdcAuthenticationHandler&gt;(&quot;Basic&quot;, null);

 services.AddAuthorization();
```

I also have

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

but, again, there is no app.UseAuthorization()

I want to be able to add [Authorize] attributes (with roles as well) and be able to access the User object inside my controller methods.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was simple. I needed the authorization tag like this:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

And

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddScheme<BasicAuthenticationOptions, EdcAuthenticationHandler>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, null);
```

There was no need for:
app.UseAuthorization();

Sorry for the trouble. Just couldn't figure out that I needed the scheme name in the authorize tag.